# Is ordinal arithmetic more complicated than classical arithmetic?

Tags: computability-theory, ordinal-numbers

Consider the first-order language $\mathcal{L}_{\text{OA}}:=(+,\cdot,0,1)$; in this language, we can formulate statements of ordinal arithmetic. Clearly, the theory $T_{\text{OA}}$ of $(\text{On},+,\cdot,0,1)$ is not recursive, as $\omega$ is definable in $\mathcal{L}_{\text{OA}}$ (as being the only ordinal $\gamma$ different from $0$, not having a predecessor and having no $\alpha$ and $\beta$ different from $0$ such that $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$ with $\alpha$ not having a predecessor) and hence the theory TA (true arithmetic) of $\mathbb{N}$ is computable from $T_{\text{OA}}$. Note that $T_{\text{OA}}$ is absolute between transitive class models of ZFC.

My question is whether the reverse reduction holds: Can we decide $T_{\text{OA}}$, given TA? More precisely, what is the Turing degree of $T_{\text{OA}}$?

Comment: Is $\langle L,\in\rangle$ interpretable in $\langle\text{Ord},+,\cdot,0,1\rangle$? I'm not sure, but if it is, then your theory will be complicated.

Comment: How do you intend to formalize $T_{OA}$? Since the ordinals are a proper class, we don't necessarily have a satisfaction class for this structure, without further explanation. In GBC+ETR, and for example therefore also in KM, we can define first-order truth for the structure $\langle \text{Ord},+,\cdot,0,1\rangle$, but I don't see just yet why we can refer to this theory in ZFC.

Comment: Addressing @JoelDavidHamkins's comment, it might be best to first consider versions of $T_{OA}$ below fixed ordinals. For instance, via Cantor normal form, I think the version of $T_{OA}$ restricted to ordinals $<\epsilon_0$ is indeed reducible to first-order arithmetic, but I don't see how to push that up to even $\omega_1$ (although we can go past $\epsilon_0$ by using more complicated notation systems of course - the real barrier seems to me to be $\omega_1^{CK}$ . . .).

Comment: Interesting point, Joel. Thanks for raising it. I would say looking at the question in KM is closer to my original intention, but the question below a fixed uncountable cardinal or even a large countable ordinal that Noah proposes is also quite interesting.

Comment: Vague recollection that I can't check right now since I'm in transit: I think Rosenstein's _Linear Orderings_ contains a proof that this is just $T_{OA}(\alpha)$ for some specific countable indecomposable $\alpha$. On the other hand, with a lot of extra functions, you get Silver machines that encode $L$ as @JoelDavidHamkins suggests.

Comment: $T_{OA}$ defined on ordinals less than your favourite recursive ordinal $\alpha$ is decidable from TA, since the relevant subset of Kleene's O is recursively enumerable, and ordinal arithmetic in Kleene's O is recursive. This argument breaks down if you try $\alpha = \omega_1^{CK}$, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using what are now called Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé Games and extensions thereof, Ehrenfeucht showed that

$$(\mathrm{Ord},{<}) \sim (\omega^\omega,{<})$$
$$(\mathrm{Ord},{<},{+}) \sim (\omega^{\omega^\omega},{<},{+})$$
$$(\mathrm{Ord},{<},{+},{\cdot}) \sim (\omega^{\omega^{\omega^\omega}},{<},{+},{\cdot})$$

where $\sim$ denotes elementary equivalence. Since $(\omega^{\omega^{\omega^\omega}},{<},{+},{\cdot})$ is a computable structure, its first-order theory is computable from $0^{(\omega)}$ ($\equiv_T TA$).

The question omits the relation $<$ but that doesn't matter for the last two results since $x < y$ is definable by $\exists z(x + 1 + z = y)$. [Thanks to Andrés Caicedo for pointing out the correct definition.]

*A. Ehrenfeucht*, [**An application of games to the completeness problem for formalized theories**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=126370), *Fund. Math.* **49** (1960-1961), 129–141.

Comment: Hm, I just realized that the OP omitted ${<}$. I guess that doesn't matter since $x < y$ can be defined as $\exists z(x + z + 1 = y)$.

Comment: Note that the use of games seems to cleverly circumvent the proper class issue with the first-order theory of $(\mathrm{Ord},\ldots)$. However, in ZFC, one must still interpret the result as scheme that, for every $n$, ZFC proves $\sim_n$.

Comment: Rather, $\exists z\,(x+1+z=y)$.

Comment: Absolutely @Andrés. Thank you for the correction! That's the price to pay for caring too much about the finite stuff...

Comment: +1. Great answer, François!

Comment: How does the answer change if we also add ordinal exponentiation? I'd suspect we'll get a structure elementarily equivalent to something like $\varepsilon_\omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is quite interesting. For the exponentiation question, I'll have a look into Ehrenfeucht's paper to see whether the techniques also solve this. Wojowu's conjecture seems quite plausible in the light of the above.

Comment: @Wojowu I don't think it can be $\epsilon_\omega$, since with exponentiation you can define the $\epsilon$ numbers, and so recognize that they have no limit point below $\epsilon_\omega$. Perhaps something like $\epsilon_{\epsilon_0}$ would work.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins That makes sense, and your  idea seems more plausible than mine. $\varepsilon_\omega$ was just a wild guess of mine.